# Solr 4.7: fq with text field for string getting invalid number

Tags: solr

In solr 4.7, search with filter query (`fq`) contains field text and search value string (space)

Getting the following error:

```
ERROR - 2014-04-02 21:47:57.903; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Invalid Number: Wing
```

Query like: `/select?q=*:*&fq=title_t:Auto+Wing`. If we pass with double quote then it works.

Previously version above query work well.

Answer (score 0):

Is your default field and ID (or some other number like field?)
Because it looks for me like the part after `+` is getting used as separate query joined by default operator and since there is no field name it takes a default one?

To verify that you can run:

```
 /select?q=:&fq=title_t:Auto+123&debug=true
```

And check how the query is constructed.

If I'm right you can just add brackets around value and you'll be fine. Adding quotations changes meaning of query a bit.

```
/select?q=:&fq=title_t:(Auto+Wing)
```

---

It's string field and copy as text(_t) field

It doesn't work Normally, needs to be enclosed by `()`

**Doesn't work :** `select?q=*:*&fq=ad_title_t:Big+monster&debug=true`
Response:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status":400,
    "QTime":2,
    "params": {
      "q":"*:*",
      "debug":"true",
      "wt":"json",
      "fq":"ad_title_t:Big monster"
    }
  },
  "error": {
    "msg":"Invalid Number: monster",
    "code":400
  }
}
```

**Works fine :** `select?q=*:*&fq=ad_title_t:(Big+monster)&debug=true`

Comment: I'm glad that brackets work. Have you tried searching for: title_t:Auto+123 (123 is important, it has to be a number). It should not complain about number type ;) And that would suggest that you have df or defaultSearchField set to some number like field